# Disable enter key in header filter field

Tags: tabulator

apologies if this has already been covered but I need to be able to disable the enter key if it is pressed in a tabulator column headerfilter field. Current behaviour is to reset the tabulator page and force a post back, which I want to avoid.
Regards,

Comment: please provide a link to a JS Fiddle or Code Pen that shows your table setup, it is hard to offer advice without knowing how your table is configured

Comment: Thanks for the reply Oli but I've sussed it now. Had to create a custom header filter :-)